# Intl not working for Android in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am getting value like **202001**.

I want to covert it like **January_2020**.

Is there a way to convert it like this?:

```
202001->January_2020
```

i tried below one.

```
const dateToStr = (input) => {
    if (input.length !== 6) {
      return "wrong date syntax, use YYYYMM";
    }
    const parts = input.match(/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})/);
    if (!parts) {
      return "wrong date syntax, use YYYYMM";
    }
    // NOTE: check syntax of parts
    const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-EN", { month: "long" })
      .format;
    const formatted = formatter(
      new Date(Date.UTC(parseInt(parts[1]), parseInt(parts[2]) - 1))
    );
    return `${formatted}_${parts[1]}`;
  };
```

it is working fine for ios but not working in android.

it showing error like:--

```
can't find variable:Intl
```

How can i get this updated value in Javascript without using any library in android and ios both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `Intl.DateTimeFormat`. You may simply use `Date` class.

```
const dateToStr = (input) => {
    if (input.length !== 6) {
      return "wrong date syntax, use YYYYMM";
    }
    const parts = input.match(/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})/);
    if (!parts) {
      return "wrong date syntax, use YYYYMM";
    }
    const monthNumber = Number(parts[2]);
    if (monthNumber < 1 || monthNumber > 12) {
        return "Wrong month number.";
    }
    const d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(monthNumber-1);
    const monthName = d.toLocaleString("en-EN", {month: "long"});
    return `${monthName}_${parts[1]}`;
  };
```